# Не активируеться клавиатура при нажатии кнопки поиска

Tags: android-toolbar, android-menu

Ребята, не могу понять в чем дело. Перепробовал уйму методов, нечего не помогает. При нажатии кнопки поиска в меню, не активируеться клавиатура. но если вешать на нее слушателя с какой либо командой то все работает. В чем может быть причина7 Вот часть main. тулбар и меню прописал.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


Toolbar mActionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);


}
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
<item
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_search"
    android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:icon="@drawable/searchcircle"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:title="Search"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение оказалось как всегда очень простое.
В строке android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
нужно изменить android: на app
Тоесть вот так
app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"